# rebasing branch more than once

Tags: git

Lately, I started to use a git rebase function to keep a **feature branch** updated with a **development branch**. 
I know the basics of `git rebase`, but can't figure if rebase function marks commits that are rebased. 
I have a scenario where I need to sync the feature branch with the dev branch quite often.

So, I did the **first rebase** and solved all conflicts, everything was fine. After a while, I needed to **sync again** with the dev branch. Rebase is now trying to resolve conflicts that are already resolved in the first rebase. 
What I'm doing wrong here and how to skip those commits that are synced with `git rebase` or `git merge`?

Comment: What you're saying is very odd ... if you really successfully rebased then the commits from your development will be in your feature branch and all your commits will be put on top ... Should you do immediately a rebase again, then it won't do anything because your branch is aligned ...

Comment: Ok, then the problem is about my rebasing. I will try with new branches one more time. What if I merge dev to feature, and then try to rebase?

Comment: I would not merge development to feature, since in the end you want the feature to be in the development branch. I always do rebases on my (short-lived) feature branches and then I can simply and easily (squash) merge back to development. But other ways are equally possible. Git (and way of working with branches) takes time to master.

Answer (score 1):

Rebased commits are not marked in any special way.

Rebase works by copying commits, as if by `git cherry-pick`, then abandoning the original commits in favor of the new and (supposedly?) improved copies.  The originals continue to exist, but if there is no way to *find* them, you won't see them any more.

Branch *names* are largely irrelevant here.  Branch names just let you find particular commits—very useful to humans, and of some use to Git, but once the commits have been found, the *names* don't matter to Git any more.  The way a branch name works is that it contains the hash ID of *one particular* commit; that commit is, by definition, the *last* commit in the branch.

What does matter, a lot, is the *commit graph*.  Every commit has its own unique hash ID, which never changes, and always means *that* commit—in fact, it means that particular commit in *every* Git, even in a Git repository that does not yet have that commit.<sup>1</sup>  Copying a commit to a new-and-improved commit results in a new, different commit with a different hash ID.<sup>2</sup>

Remember that along with the snapshot of your code, each commit carries some *metadata*, including who made it (author and committer) and when (date-and-time-stamps) and why (log message).  In this metadata, you'll also find a *parent hash ID*.  The parent of a commit is the commit that comes *before* the commit.  So given some commit, we can look backwards to find the previous commit.  If we let uppercase letters stand in for real hash IDs, we can draw this:

```
            <-H
```

The commit whose hash ID is `H` contains the hash ID of—or *points to*, for convenience—some earlier commit.  Let's all that one `G`:

```
        <-G <-H
```

Of course, `G` points back to `F`, and so on:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

A *branch name* just holds the hash ID of—i.e., points to—the *last* commit:

```
... <- F <-G <-H   <-- branch
```

Git uses the branch name to find the last commit.  Whatever commit hash ID is stored under the name `branch`, that's the last commit in the branch.  The earlier commits are implicit: they're defined by the graph, which is defined by the various "points-to" relationships stored in the commits.  Since they're in commits, they cannot be changed: nothing about any commit can ever be changed.

The usual idea behind rebase is to take some set of commits:

```
...--F--G--H--L   <-- master
            \
             I--J--K   <-- develop
```

and "transplant" them so that they come after some other commit.  To do that, Git needs to turn each *snapshot* into a set of changes, then apply those changes to some other commit.  In this case, we want to copy commit `I`, which is fine by itself, to a new-and-improved `I'`.  The difference between `I` and `I'` will be:

1. The parent of `I'` will be `L`, not `H`.
2. The snapshot in `I'` will be the result of applying `H`-vs-`I` to whatever is in `L`.

This process of taking `H`-vs-`I` and applying to `L` *is* a `git cherry-pick`: we check out commit `L` and run `git cherry-pick <hash-of-I>` to get it done.

Now that we've made `I'`:

```
                I'  <-- HEAD
               /
...--F--G--H--L   <-- master
            \
             I--J--K   <-- develop
```

we need to copy `J` to `J'`.  That's another `git cherry-pick`: we want to find what what *changed* between `I` and `J`, and apply those changes here to commit `I'`.  When done, we have:

```
                I'-J'  <-- HEAD
               /
...--F--G--H--L   <-- master
            \
             I--J--K   <-- develop
```

Now we need to copy commit `K`, with the last cherry-pick we need to do.  When we're done we have:

```
                I'-J'-K'  <-- HEAD
               /
...--F--G--H--L   <-- master
            \
             I--J--K   <-- develop
```

and we've built out our copies.  The final step of `git rebase` is to yank the *name* `develop` off commit `K` and make it point instead to commit `K'`:

```
                I'-J'-K'  <-- develop (HEAD)
               /
...--F--G--H--L   <-- master
            \
             I--J--K   [abandoned]
```

Rebase will also re-attach the special name `HEAD`, which remembers which branch we're on.  (This is why we should draw the name `HEAD` attached to some branch like this, except when Git is in its *detached HEAD* mode, which is the case during the rebase while we're copying commits, one commit at a time.  In detached HEAD mode, the special name `HEAD` contains the raw hash ID of a commit, rather than containing the name of the branch.)

---

<sup>1</sup>This particular magic is achieved by making the hash ID a checksum of the *contents* of the commit.  To help ensure uniqueness and prevent spoofing, the checksum is a cryptographic one.  But this means that if you ever try to change the contents of any commit, even just one single bit, the result is not a *changed* commit, but rather a *new* commit with a different hash ID.  The original commit remains, with the original hash ID.

<sup>2</sup>If you copy a commit and make *no* changes at all, so that the new commit is bit-for-bit identical to the original commit, you get back the original hash ID again.  So in this case there's no actual copy: but that's OK, nothing *changed*.  It *is* possible to do this in some cases, and many kinds of rebase will do it automatically when possible.  The `--force` option to `git rebase` tells Git: *Even if you could leave the commit absolutely identical, copy it anyway: change something by giving the new copy the *current* date-and-time as its committer timestamp, rather than re-using the original commit's committer timestamp.*

---

#### Things can, and do, go wrong

During each copy-a-commit (`git cherry-pick`) step, you can get merge conflicts.  This happens because the actual mechanism behind cherry-pick is Git's usual three-way merge.

Let's look at a more typical merge, where we actually start with two branches that have diverged since some common starting point:

```
          I--J   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

We'll run `git merge branch2` while on `branch1` like this.  Git will:

1. Find the *merge base:* a shared commit, one that's on *both* branches, and the *best* such one.  To do that, Git starts from where we are now—commit `J` as pointed-to by `branch1`, to which `HEAD` is attached—and working backwards, and, at the same time, starting at the other commit we name: `L`, the tip of `branch2`.  Git works backwards from `J` *and* from `L` at the same time, in a sort of graph flooding algorithm that follows the arrows backwards.

   You can think of this as *Temporarily, paint all commits green starting from `J` and working backwards.  Likewise, paint all commits red starting from `L` and working backwards.  When the two paints start mixing, we've hit a merge base.*

   In this case, commit `H` is clearly the merge base.  (There are more complicated graphs where there the merge base is not so obvious, but as long as the two branches eventually meet up, there will be *some* merge base.  In some ugly cases, there can be more than one merge base, but we'll ignore that here!)
2. Now that we have *three* commits, do the merging process: *merge as a verb*, as I like to put it.  We'll look at this more closely in a moment.
3. If all goes well, make a *merge commit*.  This uses the word *merge* as an adjective, modifying the word *commit*.  We (and Git) can even noun this word and just say *a merge*, meaning *a merge commit*.

   (If things don't go so well, Git stops, leaving you with a merge conflict.  You must fix this on your own and then run `git merge --continue`, or just `git commit`, to make the final merge commit.)

The result is a commit that works like usual: it has a snapshot as usual, and metadata with a log message as usual.  The only thing *un*-usual about it is that instead of listing *one* parent hash ID, it lists *both* parents, so that we draw it like this:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

Commit `M` is our merge commit; Git makes the name `branch1` advance to point to the new commit, as usual, so now the name `branch1` identifies commit `M` as the tip of the branch.

#### Merge conflicts occur during the *process of merging*, or merge-as-a-verb

Let's look a little bit more closely at the merge process in step 2 above.

We already know that each commit holds a snapshot.  We also know that we can have Git compare any two snapshots:

```
git diff <hash1> <hash2>
```

Git will look at all the files in the first, left-side commit, and all the files in the second, right-side commit.  When files match up, Git will inspect their *contents*.  If the contents match up, Git says nothing about those files.  If the contents *differ*, Git compares the contents and figures out a series of changes that, if applied to the left-side file, produce the right-side file.

Some files don't necessarily get matched-up at all.  The left-side file might just be deleted, and a new file might be added on the right.  Those show up in the diff as deletes and adds.  We can also ask Git to guess at *renames*, and it will try to pair up an add on the right with a delete on the left: if the files are similar enough—especially, if the contents are 100% identical—Git can match them up and say that the left-side file is *renamed* to become the right-side file, with maybe some content changes too.

What *merge as a verb* does is to run these kinds of diffs, but to run *two* of them.  We start with the merge base—which is on *both* branches—and diff it against *each* of the two branch tips:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-base> <hash-of-HEAD>   # what we changed
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-base> <hash-of-other>  # what they changed
```

For any file that *didn't* change, it's the same in all three commits and we can just use any of them.  For files that *did* change, the merge process should combine the two changes, and apply the *combined* changes to what's in the *merge base*.  That way, we keep *our* changes and add *their* changes.

Merge conflicts arise when Git can't do this combining on its own.  Git fails to combine changes when:

- we and they touched the *same* lines of the base file, and
- we and they made *different changes* to those same lines.

This "same lines" thing gets extended slightly: if we touched, say, lines 5 through 9, and they touched lines 10 and 11, that's a conflict too.  If they touched lines 11 and 12, so that line 10 is unchanged, there's no conflict.  There is no strong theoretical reason for this, it just proves to work pretty well in practice.  But note that Git doesn't *understand* the stuff it's merging, at all: it's just following simple rules about combining lines.

In any case, wherever Git is able to combine our changes and their changes, Git applies the combined changes to what's in the *merge base*.  That gives the right result.  So merge-as-a-verb means:

- diff the merge base (its snapshot) vs each commit (snapshot)
- combine the *changes*
- apply the combined changes to the *merge base's* snapshot

and it all goes well when Git thinks it combined the changes correctly.  That's true even if Git *didn't* actually combine them correctly (in some deeper sense of correct), which happens sometimes.  For instance, if we had an unused variable declared in the merge base, and on the left, we removed the declaration, and on the right, they used the variable, Git might be able to combine these.  The final result uses an undeclared variable!  (This is less likely in some programming languages than in others.)

And, of course, we get merge conflicts when Git *can't* combine the changes.

#### How all this applies to `git cherry-pick`

Earlier, we described `git cherry-pick` as "copying" a commit: find out what changed, and apply those changes to a different snapshot.  But in fact, Git uses its merge engine to do a full *merge*.

The *merge base* of this full merge is simply the *parent of the commit we want to copy*.  The `--ours` commit is the current (`HEAD`) one.  The `--theirs` commit is the *commit we want copied*.  So if we have:

```
                I'  <-- HEAD
               /
...--F--G--H--L   <-- master
            \
             I--J--K   <-- develop
```

and we're trying to copy `J` to make `J'`, we pick commit `I` as the *merge base* and commit `J` as the `--theirs` commit.  Git then does a `git diff` from commit `I` to commit `I'` to see what "we" changed.

What "we" changed, to get from `I` to `I'`, is whatever went into `I'` because of `H`-vs-`L`!  That happened in the first cherry-pick, when we were combining `H`-vs-`L` (as `--ours`, even though it's theirs) with `H`-vs-`I` (as `--theirs`, even though it is our commit that we're rebasing).

What "they" changed, to get from `I` to `J`, is of course the changes we want to copy—*our* changes from the original `develop` branch.  Combining these two sets of changes will work, but may force us to resolve conflicts.

When we do have to resolve conflicts, we `git add` our resolutions as usual, and run `git whatever --continue` to resume.  If we were using `git cherry-pick` directly, we'd use `git cherry-pick --continue`, but since we're using `git rebase`, we use `git rebase --continue`.  Git will finish the cherry-pick by making a *non*-merge, ordinary commit, in the usual way.

#### Rebasing re-conflicting and/or copying too much

Rebasing can see the same conflicts again in multiple ways.  It all depends on *which commits you copy* and *what conflicts you get and how you resolve them*.

Let's go back to the original diagram of a rebase, and look at the "after" drawing:

```
                I'-J'-K'  <-- develop (HEAD)
               /
...--F--G--H--L   <-- master
            \
             I--J--K   [abandoned]
```

We might have resolved some conflicts when we made the `I'-J'-K'` chain.  That would be OK if `I-J-K` are *really* gone, but what if the drawing is incomplete?  Suppose the original drawing should have been:

```
...--F--G--H--L   <-- master
            \
             I--J--K   <-- develop
                    \
                     M--N--O   <-- feature
```

When we copy `I-J-K` to new `I'-J'-K'` and yank the name `develop` up to point to the last copied commit, we get:

```
                I'-J'-K'  <-- develop (HEAD)
               /
...--F--G--H--L   <-- master
            \
             I--J--K
                    \
                     M--N--O   <-- feature
```

Commits `I-J-K` are *not* abandoned.  They're right there on `feature`, where they always have been!  Let's say we now merge `feature` into `master` with a regular merge:

```
                I'-J'-K'  <-- develop (HEAD)
               /
...--F--G--H--L---------------P   <-- master
            \                /
             I--J--K--M--N--O   <-- feature
```

We make the merge in the usual way, by diffing the merge base `H` against `L` to see what we changed on `master`, and diffing `H` against `O` to see what they changed on `feature`.  We combine the changes, apply the combined result to `H`, and get commit `P`, which records both parents `L` and `O`.

If we now go to rebase `feature` onto `master`, we're likely to see some conflicts.  The correct resolution is probably just to *drop* commits `I'-J'-K'` entirely, as they're already incorporated into `master`: we should just have:

```
...--F--G--H--L---------------P   <-- master, develop (HEAD)
            \                /
             I--J--K--M--N--O   <-- feature
```

as our final result.

There are lots of ways to have very similar conflicts, and because `git rebase` *repeatedly* uses cherry-pick, you can in some cases have to resolve the *same* conflict multiple times even in one rebase.  This happens when you choose their change, or include parts of it, and your changes in your own later commits in the cherry-pick sequence affect the same lines in which you used their resolution or altered your changes.

Without seeing the actual commit graph and the various snapshots that Git sees, all we can say here is that this is a general problem.  Git does not know that a rebased commit was rebased before: it's just a commit, like any other commit.  Git is going to cherry-pick it by using its parent as a merge base and diffing that merge base against your current/HEAD commit, and against the child commit you're cherry-picking.  If the changes touch the same lines, or abut, Git will declare a conflict and make you resolve it.  That's really all there is to it: *you* have to figure out whether the current commit should be copied at all, and if so, how.  *You* have to figure out if an earlier version of that commit has been incorporated into whatever commit you're using as `HEAD` in your rebase.  It's all up to you: Git only knows simple text rules.